# Why is this text not using the css prop ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this issue assigned, if the user's name is too long ⇒ it only happens in mobile view, use text-ellipsis css prop. Here's an screenShot:
[image]

Before those styles were added, the ones being pointed in the picture, the text: jadakiss from the gu lox is the shiiiiiiiiit, was breaking after the "the" and the end of it was kinda hidden behind the rating and the location. Therefore, I set `white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis` in the `<a />` tag which holds the text and set some fixed width on the div container, added a border: 1px solid red so you can see it.
I expected this to get the ellipsis css prop running but it's not working,
can anyone tell me what's left in here? any help& suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to your `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the overflow: hidden on the parent `<div>` with a `max-height` or `max-width` (in your case, max-width), not the `<a>` tag it self. `<a>` tag will never overflow if it's display property by default is inline.